# Is there a method to programmatically add a website shortcut to the iPhone?

Tags: hyperlink, iphone

I am looking to add a button to my website which easily allows people to turn the site into a shortcut on their phone.

I'm looking to automate the actions shown here: http://www.simpleleapsoftware.com/blog/how-to-create-shortcuts-iphone-ipod-touch-115 for my users, specifically for my website.

I'm open to any alternative ideas of making the process of adding a link to my website less painful, if putting a button on the site is not the easiest way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't a very helpful answer, but I seriously, seriously doubt this is possible. If Apple were to allow such an action to be automated, i.e. by pressing a button on the site, then it would be trivial for malevolent websites to do it without any kind of authorization from the user. Have you ever heard of a site that automatically adds bookmarks, say on a desktop browser? To the best of my knowledge, it can't be done, and for good reasons. If the user wants a home screen button, they'll have to add it themselves. I think the best you can do is have a simple instructional graphic that shows the user how to do it for themselves.