# How to propose to the visitor of my website to add a shortcut on his iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have a website and cordova mobile apps but it does not work with iPhones (Apple restrictions). I'm wordering if there is a way to simply add a button and propose to user to add a stylish shortcut on his iPhone homepage, for mobile-Safari & Chrome.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173934/is-there-a-method-to-programatically-add-a-website-shortcut-to-the-iphone) was asked here 9 years ago, there is any new solution ?

Many thanks